# How to solve an equation in two unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How do you solve the following systems of equations for $x$ and $y$ (such that
$ad - bc \neq 0$, and let $a, b, c, d$ be numbers):
$$ 
\left\{\begin{aligned} 
ax + by &= 1 \\
cx + dy &= 2 
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
When I try to solve it I just get bigger and bigger expressions with more and more letters, and thus can not solve anything. Not sure what you are supposed to do when there are letters instead of numbers.

Comment: You state, "$ad-bc\neq0$". That suggest you know about the determinant?

Comment: I think the devil is in what you mean by "try to solve it normally". When I try to solve it normally, the expressions stop growing quickly and I get expressions for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$, so it would help if you could elaborate on what you mean when you say "normally".

Comment: If you are using letters instead of numbers, it might be easier to just solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ in one formula and plug that into the other rather than trying row reduction.

Comment: It is actually magic: Switch $a$ and $d,$ write a minus sign in front of $b$ and $c,$ then set $x=1$ and $y=2.$ The result will give you $(ad-bc)x$ in the first equation, and $(ad-bc)y$ in the second row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addendum-2 added to respond to the second comment of blissful.

---

Addendum added to respond to the comment of blissful.

---

You want to isolate one of the variables.

Multiply the 1st equation by $c$ and the 2nd equation by $a$.

This gives

- $acx + bcy = c.$
- $acx + ady = 2a.$

Subtracting the 2nd equation from the first gives

$$y(bc - ad) = c - 2a \implies y = \frac{c - 2a}{bc - ad}. \tag1 $$

At this point, you have two choices.  One approach is to   feed in the RHS of (1) above into one of the original equations.  Perhaps easier is to repeat the exact same process as before, except that you multiply the 1st equation by $d$ and the 2nd equation by $b$.  This allows you to isolate the $x$ variable.

---

**Addendum**

Responding to the comment of blissful.

> I did that and got ...

I am not sure what you are saying here.  I will follow the simplest path to (also) compute the value of $x$.

Multiply the 1st equation by $d$ and the 2nd equation by $b$.

This gives

- $dax + dby = d.$
- $bcx + bdy = 2b.$

Subtracting the 2nd equation from the first gives

$$x(da - bc) = d - 2b \implies x = \frac{d - 2b}{da - bc}. $$

---

**Addendum-2**

Responding to the second comment of blissful.

> I calculated ... .  Then I ...

The way to verify that the answer is correct is to take the computed values of $x$ and $y$ and feed them into both of the original equations.

So you have:

- $\displaystyle x = \frac{d - 2b}{da - bc}.$
- $\displaystyle y = \frac{c - 2a}{bc - ad}.$
- $ax + by = 1.$
- $cx + dy = 2.$

Verifying:

$$\left[a \times \frac{d - 2b}{da - bc} \right] + 
\left[b \times \frac{c - 2a}{bc - ad} \right] $$

$$= \frac{1}{ad - bc} \times 
\left[ad - 2ab + 2ab - bc \right] = \frac{ad - bc}{ad - bc} = 1.$$

$$\left[c \times \frac{d - 2b}{da - bc} \right] + 
\left[d \times \frac{c - 2a}{bc - ad} \right] $$

$$= \frac{1}{ad - bc} \times 
\left[cd - 2bc + 2ad - cd \right] = \frac{2ad - 2bc}{ad - bc} = 2.$$

Comment: I did that and got $ \frac{2abcd - a^2d^2 - b^2c^2}{2abcd - a^2d^2 - b^2c^2} $ which is just  $ \frac{0}{0} $, and that is probably not correct.

Comment: @blissful See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: I calculated the value for $ x $ as well. Then I put the new values for $ x $ and $ y $ in the first equation ($ ax + by = 1 $), after that I multiplied $ a $ and $ b $ in to $ x $ and $ y $ respectively, which then gave me $ \frac{ad - 2ab}{ad - bc} + \frac{bc - 2ab}{bc - ad} $. After simplifying, I got $ \frac{2abcd - a^2d^2 - b^2c^2}{2abcd - a^2d^2 - b^2c^2} $ which is $ \frac{0}{0} $, and that is not the correct answer

Comment: @blissful See the Addendum-2 that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: From $$\left[a \times \frac{d - 2b}{da - bc} \right] + 
\left[b \times \frac{c - 2a}{bc - ad} \right] $$ you get $\frac{ad-2ab}{ad-bc}+\frac{bc-2ab}{bc-ad}$ which you can then simplify like $\frac{m}{n}+\frac{r}{s}=\frac{ms+rn}{ns}$, and then simplify again which gives you the result I mentioned earlier. I do not know what you did to get the result you show

Comment: @blissful Note that $$\frac{bc - 2ab}{bc - ad} = \frac{2ab - bc}{ad - bc}.$$  That is, you want to multiply **both** the numerator and denominator of the second fraction by $(-1)$, so that both fractions will have the common denominator of $(ad - bc).$

Comment: Why can I do that to just the second fraction? The two fractions are being added to each other, if I multiply (-1) to one fraction, I should do it to the other? I always thought LHS = RHS etc.

Comment: Please re-read my last comment.  You are multiplying **both** the numerator and denominator by $-1$.  In the same way, you have that $$\frac{-1}{-2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: My question was not about the numerator and denominator, it was about how you can multiply (-1) to only one fraction when its being added to a different fraction

Comment: @blissful Please re-read the relevant posting.  Take any fraction $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}.$  Then $$\frac{a}{b} \times \frac{-1}{-1} = \frac{-a}{-b} = \frac{a}{b}.$$  That is, if you take any fraction, and multiply both the numerator and denominator by the same non-zero number, then you have **not altered the value of the fraction**.

Comment: Okay, that is crazy, did not know you can do that